# How to simplify this jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I am using this:

```
$(this).parent('label').parent('li').parent('ul').find('img').removeClass('selectedRadio');
```

Instead of using parent 3 times how can I condense it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).parents('ul:first').find('img').removeClass('selectedRadio');
```

Just find the first UL and then remove the images.

Answer (score 5):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of chaining parents:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('img').removeClass('selectedRadio');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul > li > label img.selectedRadio", this).removeClass('selectedRadio');
```

or just

```
$("ul > li > label img", this).removeClass('selectedRadio');
```